# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (56,56) (768,768) (768,768)

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection, image-segmentation

I'm trying to perform object detection using Mask R-CNN.

```
class InferenceConfig(AirbusShipDetectionChallengeGPUConfig):
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    # 1 image for inference 
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

inference_config = InferenceConfig()

# create a model in inference mode
infer_model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", 
                          config=inference_config,
                          model_dir=WORKING_DIR)

model_path = infer_model.find_last()

# Load trained weights
print("Loading weights from ", model_path)
infer_model.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True)


# Test on a random image
image_id = np.random.choice(dataset_val.image_ids)
original_image, image_meta, gt_class_id, gt_bbox, gt_mask =\
    modellib.load_image_gt(dataset_val, inference_config, 
                           image_id)

log("original_image", original_image)
log("image_meta", image_meta)
log("gt_class_id", gt_class_id)
log("gt_bbox", gt_bbox)
log("gt_mask", gt_mask)

visualize.display_instances(original_image, gt_bbox, gt_mask, gt_class_id, 
                            dataset_train.class_names, figsize=(8, 8))

results = infer_model.detect([original_image], verbose=1)

r = results[0]
visualize.display_instances(original_image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], 
                            dataset_val.class_names, r['scores'])

# Compute VOC-Style mean Average Precision @ IoU=0.5
# Running on a few images. Increase for better accuracy.
image_ids = np.random.choice(dataset_val.image_ids, 20)
APs = []
inference_start = time.time()
for image_id in image_ids:
    # Load image and ground truth data
    image, image_meta, gt_class_id, gt_bbox, gt_mask =\
        modellib.load_image_gt(dataset_val, inference_config,
                               image_id, use_mini_mask=False)
    molded_images = np.expand_dims(modellib.mold_image(image, inference_config), 0)
    # Run object detection
    results = infer_model.detect([image], verbose=1)
    r = results[0]
    visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], 
                            dataset_val.class_names, r['scores'])

    # Compute AP
    AP, precisions, recalls, overlaps =\
        utils.compute_ap(gt_bbox, gt_class_id, gt_mask,
                         r["rois"], r["class_ids"], r["scores"], r['masks'])
    APs.append(AP)

inference_end = time.time()
print('Inference Time: %0.2f Minutes'%((inference_end - inference_start)/60))
print("mAP: ", np.mean(APs))
```

[My Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fqrUk_ZWV-Ze9QMmwuKBVM7xkDBwOO-W/view?usp=sharing)

I am getting a value error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (56,56) (768,768) (768,768)
```

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3aJH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When working with arrays of different shapes, NumPy uses the concept of broadcasting.

It is explained here:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
> element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions
> and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> - they are equal, or
> - one of them is 1
>
> If these conditions are not met, a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together` exception is thrown, indicating that the arrays
> have incompatible shapes. The size of the resulting array is the size
> that is not 1 along each axis of the inputs.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

The shapes (56,56) (768,768) (768,768) are not broadcastable, you should check your code to modify the array sizes to make them have broadcastable sizes.